# How to improve the speed of bulk_update on a foreign key of a large table?

Tags: django

The following code is working but running very slow and timing out if I try it with too many PostalCode objects. The Address model has about 1 million objects which is taking forever to query every loop. Obviously I am doing this the wrong way so any help would be appreciated! This is my first time dealing with a large set of data. I looked at and attempted transactions (it did work, but still slow) but I am not sure how that would help in this situation. If it takes time to run that is ok, no one will be using it when I do this update periodically, but it can't down for 8 hours or something like that while this process runs. I know I can offload this with celery but that I haven't got that far in my learning yet and really need to understand these fundamentals first.

Models:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    province = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
       indexes = [
           models.Index(fields=['postal_code',]),
              ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address



class PostalCode(models.Model):

    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.ForeignKey('Address', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
       indexes = [
           models.Index(fields=['postal_code',]),
              ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.postal_code
```

View:

```
def update_postal_code_addresses(request):
    
    postal_codes = PostalCode.objects.all()
    addresses = Address.objects.all()

    objs = []

    for pc in postal_codes.iterator():
        try:
            obj = addresses.get(postal_code=pc.postal_code) # this table has about 1M rows
            pc.address = obj
            objs.append(pc)

        except Address.DoesNotExist:
            pass

    PostalCode.objects.bulk_update(objs, ['address'], batch_size=100)

    return redirect('home')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetching the `Address` objects here is the bottleneck. You can fetch the `Adress` objects in bulk and use a dictionary, like:

```
def update_postal_code_addresses(request):    
    postal_codes = PostalCode.objects.all()
    addresses = Address.objects.only('pk', 'postal_code')
    address_dict = {
        address.postal_code: address.pk
        for adress in addresses.iterator()
    }

    objs = []
    for pc in PostalCode.iterator():
        adr = address_dict.get(pc.postal_code)
        if adr is not None:
            pc.address_id = adr
            objs.add(pc)

    PostalCode.objects.bulk_update(objs, ['address'], batch_size=100)

    return redirect('home')
```

Note that if there are two `Address`es with the *same* `postal_code`, then we will use one that happens to be the latest in the `addresses` queryset.

Comment: This works well after adding objs.append(pc) in the if statement and I was also getting a memory error but that was resolved with DEBUG = False in settings.py. It took about 5 minutes to process! thanks

Comment: @DickyS: arrggghhh... thanks, did not spot that. Updated.

Comment: Note that when doing this you're pulling all that data into local memory, so be mindful of how much data there is and how much memory is available. If your dev machine has several GB of RAM but your production server doesn't and/or if your local dev database is small but your production database is huge, this approach could end up working locally but failing in production.

Answer (score 0):

All the read calls to the Address table are what's making your query slow.
There are many ways to help with your query based on the resources at your disposal, but the first step would be to reduce the amount of reads you're doing by iterating into the Address table instead of gathering them one by one and by storing PostalCode in memory (assuming it's a table small enough for you to do so).

I presume PostalCode is much smaller than Address so storing PostalCode makes more sense, plus it allows us to make a subquery on Address to retrieve less items, and since you have an index on Address on the postal_code field, the query shouldn't be too expensive.

In your model, PostalCode's postal_code field isn't unique, so we'll group the PostalCode table by postal_code and assume several PostalCode may match a same postal_code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

...

def update_postal_code_addresses(request):

    # Store the PostalCode table in a dictionary mapping its postal_code with the objects associated to it.
    postal_codes= defaultdict(list)
    for postal_code in PostalCode.objects.all():
        postal_codes[postal_code.postal_code].append(postal_code)

    # Retrieve a QuerySet of Addresses that have a postal code within our PostalCode table. We only need the primary key and the postal_code to update our foreign key.
    addresses = Address.objects.filter(postal_code__in=set(postal_codes)).values_list('pk', 'postal_code')

    objs = []

    # We iterate over our addresses, updating the `address` field of our PostalCodes with the address' primary key.
    for address_id, postal_code in addresses:
        for p in postal_codes[postal_code]:
            p.address_id = address_id  # We only need the primary key of Address to set the foreign key.
            objs.append(p)

    PostalCode.objects.bulk_update(objs, ['address'], batch_size=100)

    return redirect('home')
```

This should vastly improve your performances.

Answer (score -1):

General advice. The bigger the queryset is the smaller the batch_size parameter should be. From 0 and **max** 1000 is optimal.